# Why is my code not returning a sum of k numbers within a list ls that's not greater than t?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import itertools

def choose_best_sum(t, k, ls):
    combos = itertools.combinations(ls, k)
    sums = [sum(combo) for combo in combos]
    for s in sums:
        if s > t:
            sums.remove(s)
    return max(sums)
```

This is the code I've written thus far. First, I get the combinations of all combinations of k sums in ls using `itertools.combinations()`. Then, I'm summing each of those combos, iterating over the sums, and removing all elements that are greater than my limit value, t.

But for some reason, this code isn't working. It's returning values that are greater than t in the final max(sums) return, and I can't see why that could be happening.

Comment: You should not be changing and iterating something at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess: it's because you're [removing while iterating](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques).

> It is sometimes tempting to change a list while you are looping over it; however, it is often simpler and safer to create a new list instead.

You can use a list comprehension instead (it's even more efficient):

```py
import itertools

def choose_best_sum(t, k, ls):
    return max(sum(combo) for combo in itertools.combinations(ls, k) if sum(combo) < t)
```